# Custom CSS for Webix toggle button

Tags: css, button, toggle, webix

I'm trying to repaint a toggle button, but after all attempts, I still can't find the right CSS style to overwrite.

Current implementation is http://webix.com/snippet/ebbe2e11

CSS:

```
.webix_el_toggle button{
    background-color:grey !important;
    border-color: gray !important;
}
.webix_el_toggle.webix_pressed button{
    background-color:green !important;
    border-color: green !important; 
}
```

As you can see, `.webix_el_toggle.webix_pressed` doesn't work and I've finally lost among CSS classes for the toggle. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Define "repaint". Changing the .webix_el_toggle button background-color to another color works. What is your desired look?

Comment: @Jeff.Clark I want to change the color of the pressed toggle to the green. CSS classes are different for those two states, so I'm sure it's possible, but I can't find a right class to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. The needed CSS class for the *pressed* toggle is `.webix_el_box.webix_pressed`:

```
.webix_el_toggle button{
    background-color:grey !important;
    border-color: gray !important;
}
.webix_el_box.webix_pressed button{
    background-color:green !important;
    border-color: green !important; 
}
```

**[Snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/e12a0ae7)**